# Will the specialized shared_ptr::swap() function be used if I use std::swap on a whole class?

Tags: c++, class, shared-ptr, swap

Will the std::swap() function work alright against a class which has all sorts of various objects as variable members? Especially, if some of these members are smart pointers?

```
class test
{
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<other_test>   m_other;
    ...
};

test ta, tb;
std::swap(ta, tb);
```

The `std::swap()` compiles, but I have doubts about the functionality. Specifically, I know that smart pointers have a specialized swap (i.e. `m_other.swap(rhs.m_other)`.

I'm using C++14 is that makes a difference.

Comment: It will just use your move assignment / move constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it probably won't.  If you don't overload `swap` for your own class, it will use the move operations of your class in its implementation.  These move operations are not going to use `swap` unless you implemented them yourself.

If you care about this, implement `swap` for your class:

```
class test {
    // ...
    friend void swap(test& lhs, test& rhs)
    {
        using std::swap;
        // replace a, b, c with your members
        swap(lhs.a, rhs.a);
        swap(lhs.b, rhs.b);
        swap(lhs.c, rhs.c);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Note that, until C++20, the proper way to call `swap` is via ADL:

```
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

instead of just `std::swap(a, b)`.

Since C++20, this is no longer the case — `std::swap(a, b)` automatically uses ADL to select the best overload.

Comment: Would the `std::ranges::swap()` somehow be capable of reverting to the best ADL version?

Comment: @AlexisWilke Yes.  It exists exactly to solve this problem.  See Eric Niebler's [Customization Point Design in C++11 and Beyond](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/).

Comment: @AlexisWilke I'm sorry, I screwed up.  `std::swap` is modified in place, and `std::ranges::swap` is not introduced.